# How to get post thumbnail and title into two containers through WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get posts content through WP_Query, I have:

```
function my_query( $attributes ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $posts = '';
    if($query->have_posts()) {
        $posts .= '<div class="post-wrapper">';
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $posts .= '<div class="img-container">';
                $posts .= '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            $posts .= '</div>';

            $posts .= '<div class="content-container">';
                $posts .= '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
            $posts .= '</div>';
        }
        $posts .= '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $posts;
    }
```

And it's working, I'm getting in my html something like this:

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div><img src="..." alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <span>some title</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div><img src="..." alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <span>some title</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div><img src="..." alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <span>some title</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I need to divide my containers images and titles like this:

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div><img src="..." alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="..." alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="..." alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <span>some title</span>
        <span>some title</span>
        <span>some title</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do this properly?

Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue for [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but I think an easier solution for now without changing your code structure very much (and without relying on looping through the posts multiple times), would be to build multiple variables instead of just one `$posts` variable, and then combine them after the `while` loop. Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$container = $images = $titles = ''; // Start with 3 variables

if( $query->have_posts() ){
    // Start the $container;
    $container .= '<div class="post-wrapper">';
        // Build the $images and $titles separately;
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();

            $images .= '<div class="img-container">';
                $images .= '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            $images .= '</div>';

            $titles .= '<div class="content-container">';
                $titles .= '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
            $titles .= '</div>';
        }

        // Now that $images and $titles are build, add them to the $container;
        $container .= $images;
        $container .= $titles;

    // Now close the container
    $container .= '</div>';

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $container;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is great!

Answer (score 0):

You can call [have_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/) more than once, assuming there are no more posts in the loop. It will rewind to the beginning.

```
function my_query( $attributes ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $query = new \WP_Query($args);
        $posts = '';
        if($query->have_posts()) {
            $posts .= '<div class="post-wrapper"><div class="img-container">';
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                    $posts .= '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            }
            $posts .= '</div><div class="content-container">';
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                $posts .= '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
            }
            $posts .= '</div></div>';
            wp_reset_postdata();
            return $posts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this method, but I think it's not the proper one.